# Cleaner Way to Write Conditional Statement in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have the following python script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

home_dict = []

for year in range(2005, 2021):
    if year == 2020:
        for month in range(1, 6):
            url = 'https://www.rebgv.org/market-watch/MLS-HPI-home-price-comparison.hpi.all.all.' + str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-1.html';
            r = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

            home_table = soup.find('div', class_="table-wrapper")
            for home in home_table.find_all('tbody'):
                rows = home.find_all('tr')
                for row in rows:
                    area = row.find('td').text;
                    benchmark = row.find_all('td')[1].text
                    priceIndex = row.find_all('td')[2].text
                    oneMonthChange = row.find_all('td')[3].text
                    sixMonthChange = row.find_all('td')[4].text
                    oneYearChange = row.find_all('td')[5].text
                    threeYearChange = row.find_all('td')[6].text
                    fiveYearChange = row.find_all('td')[7].text
                    propertyType = row.find_all('td')[8].text
                    year = year;
                    month = month;

                    home_obj = {
                        "Area": area,
                        "Benchmark": benchmark,
                        "Price Index": priceIndex,
                        "1 Month +/-": oneMonthChange,
                        "6 Month +/-": sixMonthChange,
                        "1 Year +/-": oneYearChange,
                        "3 Year +/-": threeYearChange,
                        "5 Year +/-": fiveYearChange,
                        "Property Type": propertyType,
                        "Report Month": month,
                        "Report Year": year
                    }
                    home_dict.append(home_obj)
    else:
        for month in range(1, 13):
            url = 'https://www.rebgv.org/market-watch/MLS-HPI-home-price-comparison.hpi.all.all.' + str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-1.html';
            r = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

            home_table = soup.find('div', class_="table-wrapper")
            for home in home_table.find_all('tbody'):
                rows = home.find_all('tr')
                for row in rows:
                    area = row.find('td').text;
                    benchmark = row.find_all('td')[1].text
                    priceIndex = row.find_all('td')[2].text
                    oneMonthChange = row.find_all('td')[3].text
                    sixMonthChange = row.find_all('td')[4].text
                    oneYearChange = row.find_all('td')[5].text
                    threeYearChange = row.find_all('td')[6].text
                    fiveYearChange = row.find_all('td')[7].text
                    propertyType = row.find_all('td')[8].text
                    year = year;
                    month = month;

                    home_obj = {
                        "Area": area,
                        "Benchmark": benchmark,
                        "Price Index": priceIndex,
                        "1 Month +/-": oneMonthChange,
                        "6 Month +/-": sixMonthChange,
                        "1 Year +/-": oneYearChange,
                        "3 Year +/-": threeYearChange,
                        "5 Year +/-": fiveYearChange,
                        "Property Type": propertyType,
                        "Report Month": month,
                        "Report Year": year
                    }
                    home_dict.append(home_obj)
        
                
print(home_dict)
```

This script is web scraping a website. If the year is 2020, it would only scape from January to May. For other years, it would go from Jan to Dec.

You can tell that the body of the script is repeated inside that if-else conditional statement, is there an easier way to write this to make it look cleaner and not repeat itself?

Comment: Do you always forever want it to be limited to May 2020, or is it that we happen to be in June 2020 right now? If its July, does it go to June? You could use the `calendar` module to iterate months or you could just keep iterating increasing years and months until your `requests.get` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Turns out `calendar` is lousy for iterating months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try a `try` clause?

```
for year in range(2005, 2021):
    month in range(1, 13):
        try:
            <your code>
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: I tried this `for year in range(2005, 2021):
    if year == 2020:
        availableMonth = 6
    else:
        availableMonth = 13
    for month in range(1, availableMonth):` but I think your way makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

Just define a `dict` with year as key & range of month as values,

```
filter_ = {2020 : (1, 6)}

for year in range(2005, 2021):
    start, stop = filter_.get(year, (1,13))

    for month in range(start, stop):
        url = 'https://www.rebgv.org/market-watch/MLS-HPI-home-price-comparison.hpi.all.all.' + str(
            year) + '-' + str(month) + '-1.html'
        r = requests.get(url)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As scraping for 1 to 6 months is common for all the years. You can **scrape** those years first. And then if the year is not equal to 2020 you can **scrape** rest of the years